# joi validationerror 'value' must be an array

Tags: json, joi

I am new to JSON. I have a schema mentioned as :

*

```
const schema = Joi.array().min(3).has({
    Name: Joi.string().required(),
    Type: Joi.string().required(),
    Price: Joi.number().required(),
});
```

- 

My JSON is like :

```
{
    "foods": [
    {
      "Name": "Item1",
      "Type": "Category1",
      "Price": 14
    },
    {
      "Name": "Item2",
      "Type": "Category2",
      "Price": 8
    },
    {
      "Name": "Item3",
      "Type": "Category1",
      "Price": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I validating this, I am getting error as:
joi validationerror 'value' must be an array.

Please let me know what needs to be changed in JSON object to be validated by the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema expects an array with minimum lenght of 3 as root, but you are passing an object with a single property `foods`, which then is an array. So you must get rid of the surrounding object.

This would be a valid input to your validator

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Item1",
    "Type": "Category1",
    "Price": 14
  },
  {
    "Name": "Item2",
    "Type": "Category2",
    "Price": 8
  },
  {
    "Name": "Item3",
    "Type": "Category1",
    "Price": 10
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. My understanding that JSON always starts with {} wrong. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As derpirscher answered, your schema expects an array first. To validate the JSON you have, the schema must be:

```
const newSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    food: schema
})
```

I used the constant 'schema' you previously created, to simplify this one.